# How to revert part of a commit?

Tags: git, revert, git-revert

There is a commit, pushed etc in the history of our repo. I have the SHA, and I would like to run the equivalent of `git revert /one/folder/* THESHAID`, but git revert doesn't look like it has the ability to change only a specific folder.

Is there a way to replicate that functionality?

Comment: You can manually edit the patch so that it contains changes in the desired directory only and then revert the patch (patch -R -p1 <patch>) & commit.

Answer (score 1):

This is oddball enough it's no surprise there isn't a pushbutton for it, especially when the brute force method is so easy:

```
git revert that_commit           # do the whole revert
git reset --hard HEAD^           # in what turns out to have been a throwaway commit
git checkout HEAD@{1} -- one/folder   # and just take what you want of the results
```

Comment: I just voted to close this as a dup too, @vcsjones's linked answer is conceptually cleaner but clunkier in execution, take your pick.

Comment: I checked out the other answer.. the logic of these commands makes a lot more sense to me...